# Destructuring custom class

Tags: scala

I would like to destructure the following class

```
case class Box(name: Text, value: Text) extends Product2[Text, Text] {
    override def _1: Text = name
    override def _2: Text = value
    override def canEqual(that: Any): Boolean = ???
  }
```

in a for loop, like this

```
val boxes: List[Box] = // ...
for ((name, value) <- boxes) { /* ... */ }
```

I implemented the class to match implementation of `Tuple2`. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't need it to be a `Tuple2`; just `case class Box(name: String, value: String)` and you can them loop on items this way: `List(Box("A", "1"), Box("B", "2")).foreach { case Box(name, value) => println(s"$name $value") }`

Comment: please clean up your question - so it helps others! Accept one of the answers or add your own answer that fixed your problem - or comment if you still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To destructure a class, you need to [define an `unapply` method taking this class, normally in its companion object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html). By declaring it as a `case class`, this method already exists (and you can't define it manually).

But making it a case class also automatically `extends Product2[Text, Text]` and overrides `canEqual` (properly, not with `???`), so you don't need these. Or `_1` and `_2`; those are methods specifically for tuples. Leaving, as Xavier's comment says,

```
case class Box(name: Text, value: Text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in a for-loop:

```
for (Box(name, value) <- boxes) { /* ... */ }
```

Just add `Box` and you have what you want

Comment: It works in general, for loop is not a special case:
`val Box(name, value) = box`